# Select items from a collection based on the sub-class type in the collection

Tags: c#

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : A {}

ICollection<A> myCollection;
var myresults = myCollection.Where(item => item.GetType() is C);
```

Given the hierarchy above the where predicate effectively does nothing.

How can I structure the where predicate to return all items of type C from the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of where you can use [`OfType<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
var myresults = myCollection.OfType<C>();
```